# Adding static files at runtime in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Java Spring Application and I need to serve some static content, so I use the well documented approach as described in e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources. I create a folder src/main/resources/static, I add a file test.json. I build and run the app, and I can access localhost:8080/test.json

But if I want to add another file, e.g. test2.json I need to restart the server in order for the app to serve it.

Is there a way to "force a new file search" and circumvent the caching so that I can add files at runtime without writing a new Controller?

Performance doesn't matter to me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to add your dynamic files to the a location on the filesystem, and then add a custom resource handler.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceHandlerRegistry) {
     resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/fs_resources/**")
       .addResourceLocations("file:///my/path/where/i/keep/stuff")
       .setCachePeriod(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, so I did the same thing, except that I implemented WebMvcConfigurer interface instead. But that doesn't work either unfortunately

Comment: I've updated with a solution that should work, put a break point in the method to ensure that it's being executed during bootstrap.

Comment: Voting up since that probably does the job. It was probably my bad, used a path in :classpath, which at build time goes to /target folder. Won't check since it was part of a solution that won't work anyway (involved some crazy CI/CD ideas). Thanks for your answer :-)